# Происхождение слова "впаривать"

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Когда пытаются навязать человеку какой-то товар, то на сленге это называется "впаривать". Но, интересно, от какого слова это произошло? От слова "пар" или слова "пара" (то есть, давать что-то в пару к чему-то)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю от рекламной акции, когда вместе с основным товаром "впаривают" ещё какой-нибудь ненужный дешёвый аксессуар. Фактически этот аксессуар в цену товара входит, но преподносится как бесплатный бонус привлекая внимание клиента. Например, не так давно видек как одна чайная компания вместе с большой упаковкой чая продавала довольно дешёвые кружки.

В интернете попадались и другие версии, правда адекватную удалось найти только [одну](http://www.security-bridge.com/blogs/vparivat/):

> Раньше существовало близкое по смыслу слово "парить". Происходит оно, как мне кажется, не от священнодействия в русской парной, а изначально было введено в оборот таксистами еще в прошлом веке, и смысл этого слова в следующем. Чтобы хорошо "нагреть" (это близкий по смыслу термин, означает "обсчитать") подвыпившего пассажира, водитель такси незаметно включал печку, отчего пассажиру становилось совсем хорошо (как в парилке). После такой поездки и расчета с водителем пассажира впору было напутствовать: "С легким паром!".

Answer (score 2):

Слово появилось с одесского Привоза, где торговало много греков. Типичные фразы торговца-грека:

- Πάρε αυτό! Πάρε αυτό! (Возьми это!). Тры рубли!

Ответ покупателя:

- Па́ре, па́ре! Шо ты мне тут впариваешь!? Товар г...но!

Answer (score 0):

http://books.google.az/books?id=lVjlAAAAMAAJ&hl=ru&pg=PA329&img=1&pgis=1&dq=%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%92%D0%9F%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%AC&sig=ACfU3U2r4FQIrGMAnG8QHloH3dQfGnwQ2A&edge=0

Comment: Ссылка — это не ответ. Пожалуйста, пишите хоть что-то от себя.

Comment: хорошее правило,я не буду отвечать ссылками,но благодарен всем,кто ответит на мои вопросы ссылками.

Answer (score 0):

Это сленговое слово. Появилось не так давно. Жаль, что автор сразу не написал словарную статью по этому поводу.